# How to make <li> elements in the <ul> aligned on the right side (bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I try to make < li > elememts in one < ul > on the right wide to be aligned in one line, how can I do that?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Library</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- omitted -->
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="/viewrecord" class="btn btn-primary">View Circulation Record</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form action="/logout" method="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://ibb.co/chZwrLD

Comment: https://ibb.co/chZwrLD <-- there is my current design, but failed to aligned in one line.

Comment: i didn't understand your proper requirement but i think float:left will work

Comment: float: left does not work since I use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Library</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- omitted -->
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row">
            <li>
                <a href="/viewrecord" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">View Circulation Record</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <form action="/logout" method="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**strong text**

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please describe what you made for the future reader. Like add the class `flex-row` and what does it do.